# How to not display () and '

Tags: python, function

I'm running a file with 2 functions, it Works correctly but it display the following when I run it:

```
Enter your weight (in Kilograms): 81

Enter your height (in Centimeters): 175

Enter your age: 20

Enter 5 if you are a male or -161 if you are female: 5

('You have to consume between: ', 1447.0, 'and', 1537.4375, 'calories a day.')
```

Below is my code:

```
def calBurned(weight:float, height:float, age: int, genderValue:float)->str:
    TMB = (10*weight)+(6.25*height)-(5*age) + genderValue
    minCal = TMB*0.80
    maxCal = TMB*0.85
    text = "You have to consume between ", minCal, "and", maxCal, "calories a day."
    return text

def calRec()->None:
    weight = float(input("Enter the your weight (in Kilograms): " ))
    height = float(input("Enter your height (in Centimeters): "))
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    genderValue = float(input("Enter 5 if you are a male or -161 if you are female: "))
    calRecom= calBurned(weight, height, age, genderValue)
    print(calRecom)

calRec()
```

Is it posible to return just the text without the all the (',')?

Answer (score 2):

Your `text` is a tuple. You can convert each of its items to a string and return the concatenation of them:

```
text = " ".join(map(str, text))
```

You can also build `text` as a string in the first place:

```
text = f"You have to consume between {minCal} and {maxCal} calories a day."
```

Last but not least, a function should not return formatted text;  it should return the results of computations `(minCal,maxCal)`. Formatting should be done by the caller.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I'll take your considerations into account

Answer (score 1):

In `calcBurned` you didn't concatenate the strings, rather you made it a tuple, in this line:

```
text = "You have to consume between ", minCal, "and", maxCal, "calories a day."
```

change all the commas (,) to pluses (+), and change `minCal` and `maxCal` to `str(minCal)` and `str(maxCal)`, and it should work:

```
text = "You have to consume between " + str(minCal) + " and " + str(maxCal) + " calories a day."
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
text = "You have to consume between {} and {} calories a day.".format(minCal, maxCal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
text = "You have to consume between ", minCal, "and", maxCal, "calories a day."
```

to

```
text = f"You have to consume between {minCal} and {maxCal} calories a day."
```